# Looping over a list to create elements

Tags: elm

This seems to be set up correct, but it clearly is not and I cannot see where it's going wrong. I'm trying to loop over a "list of objects" and create a `ul` with `li`s for each item in the list and put those inside of a `div`. Ignore everything involving the ID. I have a feeling I'm not entirely sure how `List.map` returns.

```
type alias Product =
  { a : String
  , b : String
  , c : Int
  , d : String
  , e : String
  }

type alias Model =
  { id : String
  , products : List Product}

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ input [ type' "text", onInput UpdateText ] []
    , button [ type' "button", onClick GetProduct ] [ text "Search" ]
    , br [] []
    , code [] [ text (toString model.products) ]
    , div [] [ renderProducts model.products ]
    ]

renderProduct product =
  let
    children =
      [ li [] [ text product.a ] 
      , li [] [ text product.b ] 
      , li [] [ text (toString product.c) ] 
      , li [] [ text product.d ] 
      , li [] [ text product.e ] ]
  in
    ul [] children

renderProducts products =
  List.map renderProduct products
```

The error is as follows:

```
The 2nd argument to function `div` is causing a mismatch.

  78|       div [] [ renderProducts model.products ]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `div` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

  List (VirtualDom.Node a)

But it is:

  List (List (Html a))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`renderProducts` returns a list of elements. The second parameter of `div` takes a list of elements. By enclosing the second parameter in brackets, you are creating a list containing a single list of elements. That's why the error message says

> ```
> But it is:
>
>     List (List (Html a))
> ```

You should instead do this:

```elm
div [] (renderProducts model.products)
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be some sort of oversight.